# To create a list of all file name & it's data. The first element of list should be the file name & second element should be it's corresponding data

Tags: python, list, for-loop, text

Note, the **first element** of the list should be the filename and **second element** should be it's corresponding data.

**And I've to do this for all the files in the file_path**

```
for i in file_path:
    txt_file=open(i, 'r')
    data = txt_file.read()
    k=0 
    filename[k] = filename[k]+':'+data
    k+=1
        
    txt_file.close()
```

filename = ['PATIENT#3 PAGE 1.txt','PATIENT #3 PAGE 2.txt','PATIENT #5 PAGE 1.txt','PATIENT #5 PAGE 2.txt',..]

file_path = ['C:\Users\OCR_output\PATIENT #3 PAGE 1.txt,'C:\Users\OCR_output\PATIENT #3 PAGE 2.txt']

> My output needs to look like this: [filename1, 'the text data inside
> file1', 'filename2', 'the text data inside file2']

Please help me to get the desired output.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first things first: you are updating `k` in every iteration of the for-loop so it always becomes `0`. So you are only updating the first element. We can fix this by simply putting the `k` outside of the loop:

```py
k=0 
for i in file_path:
    txt_file=open(i, 'r')
    data = txt_file.read()
    filename[k] = filename[k]+':'+data
    k+=1
        
    txt_file.close()
```

Now I'm going to show a few improvements to this code, assuming the description you have given. First, let's use a `with` statement to avoid manually opening and closing the file:

```
k=0
for i in file_path:
    with open(i, 'r')as txt_file:
        data = txt_file.read()
        filename[k] = filename[k]+':'+data
        k+=1
```

furthermore, you can use `append` to add data to your collection, which I'm assuming you want:

```py
for path in file_path:
    with open(path, 'r')as txt_file:
        data = txt_file.read()
        filename.append(i)
        filename.append(data)
        # or: filename.extend([i, data])
```